# Vertx/Hazelcast: How to find out current port number of cluster member?

Tags: java, port, hazelcast, vert.x

By default hazelcast can choose portnumbers between 5700-5800 for the cluster members. Is there is a possiblity to get the current Portnumber of the cluster member/Verticle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive found I think the answer by myself:

The method I have been searching is:

```
hazelcastInstance.getCluster().getLocalMember();
```